# Looking for an advanced sample player (scrub, grain, transpose, scratching...)

Tags: sampler, scratching, granular-synthesis

Hi mates,
I am looking for an advanced way of playing my own samples, recordings and experimentations in an "instrumental" way. That means : controlling play position, "grain" pausing, vari-speed, scratching, loop cues, applying realtime FX and being able to record the output as an audio file.
What piece of software/hardware would you recommend ? Is there any DJing stuff that could suit my needs, even with non metrical sounds ?

Thanks,

Xavier

PS : I am an ableton live, EW, and NI user.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Max for Live with your Ableton? If so check out Granulator. Also have a look at  [m4l library](http://maxforlive.com/library/index.php)

This is also a cool granular sample recorder and player from [Density](http://www.densitygs.com/) Even the iPad version is great.

Your'e covered if your'e a NI user as well. Search in the [Reaktor user library](http://www.native-instruments.com/?id=userlibrary)
 for granular and I'm sure you'll find something you like. I have used the good old Plasma a lot, but there is plenty of new things since that was developed. I just love the way it sounds...

Comment: Many thanks. I will explore those tools. Density's products seem to be what I have been looking for. I will try granulator as well.

Answer (score 0):

Kontakt is great for all of that.

Some good fun can be had by mapping the sample start position to your mod wheel and the sample pitch to a fader. Map some FX parameters to your faders and hit record.

Answer (score 0):

Live should cover all of your recording, performance, realtime, automation etc stuff nicely.

As for the sample manipulation; Today might be your lucky day, because NI just released a freebie instrument for Reaktor called Skanner, which appears to do a bunch of the stuff you mention specifically. http://www.native-instruments.com/#/en/products/producer/powered-by-reaktor/skanner/?content=1823

If you don't have Reaktor, I can very highly recommend Camel Alchemy for all forms of sample manipulation, including granular stuff. It's the best.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expensive solution, but I am an avid Kyma user, and love to use my iPad as the front end. You can manipulate samples endlessly, and the sound quality is the bet I've ever heard. Plan on spending a few grand and several months to get fluid with the system, but it is absolutely amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://koti.teak.fi/~meriksso/maxmsp/sora.html) out. Max4Live, too.

/Markus